# Axlsx-Rails gem not working properly, show missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xlsx, axlsx

I have a link like this

```
<%= link_to "download file", import_horse_report_horses_path(format: 'xlsx') %>
```

Then in the controller action I have following code

```
 def import_horse_report
    @horses = ImportHorse.all        
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx{ }
    end
  end
```

For this action I have this template import_horse_report.xlsx.axlsx

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Horses") do |sheet|
  @horses.each do |horse|
    sheet.add_row [horse.breed, horse.date_of_birth, horse.gender]
  end
end
```

I am using axlsx_rails gem and following its documentation. But I get this error

```
Missing template horses/import_horse_report, application/import_horse_report with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xlsx], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :rabl]}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: where you saved this `import_horse_report.xlsx.axlsx` template ? path ?

Comment: In the same directory where views for other action of this controller

Comment: Home/Horsecount/app/views/horses

Comment: looks correct, i guess you have to correct this `format.xlsx{ }
` to `format.xlsx`

Comment: thats not working as well

Comment: What rails version are you using? I've seen something similar with an issue for rendering an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

you could try specifically what xls to be render by changing

```
format.xlsx{ }
```

to

```
format.xlsx{ filename =>'import_horse_report.xlsx' }
```

ref:
https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails

Answer (score 0):

Try an explicit render statement:

```
format.xlsx { render xlsx: 'import_horse_report' }
```

If you are calling `/horses/import_horse_report` without the trailing `.xlsx` the render statement will not be executed unless you force the `:xlsx` format in the routes file. If you want to keep your `respond_to` block, change your url. Otherwise you can drop the `respond_to` block for a simple `render :xlsx` statement (provided you will never serve anything else.)

Comment: There is one very simple possibility. Are you calling `/horses/import_horse_report.xlsx` or `/horses/import_horse_report`? If it is the latter it won't find the template without forcing the format using `routes`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using

```
render xlsx: "import_horse_report"
```

rather than the respond_to. That might be an option depending on your situation.